# Cabal installation issues

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am having some issues installing packages using cabal. Issuing the following command:

```
> cabal install ghc-mod stylish-haskell haskell-docs hdevtools
```

produces these errors

```
Building yaml-0.8.8.3...
Preprocessing library yaml-0.8.8.3...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id aeson-0.7.0.6-b19228a032fb34be4eef122
913c6e81a
    (use -v for more information)
Failed to install yaml-0.8.8.3
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghc-mod-4.1.1 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 which failed to install.
haskell-docs-0.2.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 failed while unpacking the package. The exception
was:
C:\Users\Arnob\AppData\Local\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-5840\haskell-src-ext
s-1.15.0.1\dist-tmp:
MoveFileEx
"C:\\Users\\Arnob\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-5840\\haskell
-src-exts-1.15.0.1\\dist-tmp"
"C:\\Users\\Arnob\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-5840\\haskell
-src-exts-1.15.0.1\\dist":
permission denied (Access is denied.)
hdevtools-0.1.0.5 depends on unix-2.7.0.1 which failed to install.
hlint-1.8.61 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 which failed to install.
stylish-haskell-0.5.10.0 depends on yaml-0.8.8.3 which failed to install.
unix-2.7.0.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yaml-0.8.8.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have also tried installing the windows fork of hdevltools by running

```
> cabal install
```

on the cloned github repo.  However this also produces errors.

As a last ditch effort, I tried changing the remote repo to "stackage", i.e.

```
remote-repo: stackage: http://www.stackage.org/stackage/44ea140bd97cbb0f6140d331f8f7f8667a637eda
```

but this did not help either.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you build this in a sandbox (use `cabal sandbox init; cabal install --only-dependencies; cabal build`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a Windows specific issue, where cabal cannot move some required files in the `haskell-src-exts` distribution (the issue is also seen in other packages, such as `pandoc`).  This might be related to the issue reported here: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1698

I was able to get the `haskell-src-exts` package installed by doing the following:

```
> cabal unpack haskell-src-exts
> cd haskell-src-exts
> cabal install
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is listed right in Cabal's error message:

```
MoveFileEx ... ...:
permission denied (Access is denied.)
```

So it seems you have a permission problem with your Windows installation (or at least your user temp folder), which is why Cabal stumbles.

Comment: I do not believe this is a permissions issue, because I have also tried running the command after launching the command prompt as administrator.  The administrator account should have unlimited privileges to move and create files.

Comment: To my knowledge, the Administrator account only has the right to make any file / directory read / writable for whoever he sees fit (including himself). But it does not necessarily have the needed rights. Although you already solved your issue, I just wanted to say.